# JSLint - Unexpected '\' before '.'

Tags: javascript, regex, jslint

I am getting the following warning in JSLint for my regex expression.

[image]

```
Unexpected '\' before '.'.
var regexForEmail = /^(([^<>()\[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@(([^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+\.)+[^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\"]{2,})$/i;
```

Can someone help me how to fix it or is there any other way to suppress the warning?

Thanks in advance

Dinesh.

Comment: What are you using that generates that output?

Comment: i am copying my javascript and pasting it in the mentioned link http://www.jslint.com/ . this will generate the warnings in my js file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.` doesn't have special meaning when it's inside square brackets, so there's no need to escape it there. `"` has no special meaning at all in regular expressions, so you never need to escape it.

```
var regexForEmail = /^(([^<>()\[\].,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\].,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@(([^<>()\[\].,;:\s@"]+\.)+[^<>()\[\].,;:\s@"]{2,})$/i;
```

The only characters that are special inside square brackets are backslash, hyphen, right square bracket, and caret at the beginning.

See [What special characters must be escaped in regular expressions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/399078/what-special-characters-must-be-escaped-in-regular-expressions)

Comment: Using your expression still shows me the warning

`Expected '\' before '['.
var regexForEmail = /^(([^<>()[\].,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\].,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@(([^<>()[\].,;:\s@"]+\.)+[^<>()[\].,;:\s@"]{2,})$/i;`

Comment: I'm not sure why JSLint thinks that `[` needs to be escaped inside `[]`, but I've added back those backslashes. I also missed some double quotes that still were escaped, I've fixed them. I just tested this in jslint.com, there are no warnings now.